# how to recursively visit all tree node

Tags: c++, binary-tree

So, I got a tree like this

```
                        a
                       /  \
                      b     c
                     / \   /
                    d   e  f
```

the function have to print:

```
a
ab
abd
abe
ac
acf
```

my teacher say that the only argument that I can have is a pointer to the first node. I can't use any other variable including static and global variable.

```
void print(Node* a)
{
  if(a==NULL){return;}
  cout<<a->data;
  if(a->left!=NULL){print(a->left);}
  if(a->right!=NULL){print(a-right);}
}
```

So far, my program can only print "abdecf". any suggestion?

Comment: can you post the code/alogorithm that prints `"abdecf"` ?

Comment: it seems like you need to print the parent of each node too

Comment: do you mean the recursion call something like: "print(a);print(a->left);

Comment: Are you allowed to use local variables? Or an additional function that takes other arguments? It's going to be difficult without them.

Comment: @beta nope. that's the problem.

Comment: Are `left`, `right`, and `data` the only members in the `Node` structure/class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could is add a parent to the structure that represents a node. Like so -

```
class Node {
public:
  char data;
  Node *left;
  Node *right;
  Node *parent;
};
```

So now with this modified data structure, you will print at every level the path from the current node to the root, like so -

```
void print(Node* a)
{
  Node *cur = a;
  do {
    cout << cur->data << ", ";
    cur = cur->parent;
  } while(cur != NULL);
  if(a->left != NULL){
    print(a->left);
  }
  if(a->right != NULL){
    print(a->right);
  }
}
```